# Update a field in an object in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is the example provided in the documentation to update a field within a nested object in firebase.

```
var frankDocRef = db.collection("users").doc("frank");
frankDocRef.set({
name: "Frank",
favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", subject: "recess" },
age: 12
});

// To update age and favorite color:
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
"age": 13,
"favorites.color": "Red"
})
.then(function() {
console.log("Document successfully updated!");
});
```

Instead of updating the favourites, I want to add to favourites would someone point me in the right direction on how to do this.

Let's say I want to

```
firebase: "Help"
the the resulting favourites object should be
favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", subject: "recess", firebase: "Help" },
```

I used set with the dot operation but it overrides everything instead.

Answer (score 46):

To add an entry to a set (a Javascript Object), use `DocumentReference.update`:

```
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
  "favorites.firebase": "Help")}
})
```

will result in

```
favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", subject: "recess", firebase: "Help" }
```

Comment: Anyway we can do this dynamically? say favorites.someUid?

Comment: You could use templateStrings. `const update = {};`. Then set update fields like this `update[\`favorites.${someUid}\`] = 'abc';` and update the collection `db.collection("users").doc("frank").update(update)`

Comment: @Vispercept I have a case like `let update_id = {
department:{  }
}` , now I want to add new data inside the department object. how to update the department map without getting the previous value?

Answer (score 1):

in case someone looking for latest update for 2023, i got from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data)

```
import { doc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const userRef = doc(db, "users", "frank");

await updateDoc(userRef, {
    "favorites.color": "Red"
});
```